# SignalR Send data to client on interval based on Client side parameter

Tags: c#, angularjs, signalr, signalr-hub

I am working on a Project that requires automatic updates to the client on an interval But the updates sent to the client are based on Parameters selected by the Client.

And the Client I am working for has said that the Client should not initiate the Request to the server, but the Server should send the data to the client.

I followed the article here to get SignalR to send data to the client on intervals. [Build a Real-time SignalR Dashboard with AngularJS](http://www.sitepoint.com/build-real-time-signalr-dashboard-angularjs/)

So for Example I have a News Widget, which the user can enter a string and get news based on that, then the server should automatically push updated news to the client.

This is what the widget looks like

[image]

So when the user has entered `C`, the Server should push the news related to `C` to this user.

This is what my `WidgetEngine` looks like, This is responsible for sending the updates to the Client:

As you can see that the method `_dalProvider.GetNewsHeadlines("S")` I have hard coded the Symbol.

I thought about saving the Searched symbol in `Session` But with `WebSockets` that is a `NO`

```
public async Task OnPerformanceMonitor()
{
    var widgetList = new List<WidgetModel>
    {
        new NewsWidgetModel { WidgetName = "News", },
    };

    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(_pollIntervalMillis);

        IList<WidgetModel> widgetModels = new List<WidgetModel>();
        foreach (var widgetItem in widgetList)
        {
            try
            {
                switch (widgetItem.WidgetName)
                {
                    case "News":

                        widgetModels.Add(new NewsWidgetModel()
                        {
                            WidgetName = "News",
                            News = _dalProvider.GetNewsHeadlines("S")
                        });
                        break;
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
                {
                }
            }

            // At the moment I am broadcasting to all the clients, will send to connected user later.
            _hubs.Clients.All.broadcastPerformance(widgetModels);
            _hubs.Clients.All.serverTime(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Is there somewhere I can save this on the server side, and then I can query database?

Comment: You could try a redis cache, but it seems like you want some kind of web job (azure thing)

Comment: @CallumLinington any idea on how to do that?

Comment: So I re-read you post, I'm nearly 95% certain that you need some kind of service running constantly that can push these events. It will be SignalR on the client side that will connect to this service. Then it will be up to the service that will read the users settings (from wherever, db, redis, memory) and abide by those settings to push updates to the client.